# How to Save files with a FileUpload Interface (GUI) to a chosen location in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, file, directory, save

This comes down to simply saving to a specific location in asp.net.
Similar to using 'Save as...' in any standard program like Microsoft Word.

The GUI I'm looking for is exactly the same as the GUI for the FileUpload control in asp.net.
However, the FileUpload control only allows you to upload files to your running program.
All I want is to select a location to Save a file that is created within the program.

I've already written the following code:

```
        protected void btnSaveYourBuild_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
```

// Section A

```
        System.Drawing.Image chosenGoldenLineTop = GetSystemDrawingImage(ImageGoldenLineTop);
        System.Drawing.Image chosenGoldenLineBottom = GetSystemDrawingImage(ImageGoldenLineBottom);
        System.Drawing.Image chosenImageTop = GetSystemDrawingImage(ImageTop);
        System.Drawing.Image chosenImageJungle = GetSystemDrawingImage(ImageJungle);
        System.Drawing.Image chosenImageMid = GetSystemDrawingImage(ImageMid);
        System.Drawing.Image chosenImageAdc = GetSystemDrawingImage(ImageAdc);
        System.Drawing.Image chosenImageSupp = GetSystemDrawingImage(ImageSupp);
```

// Section B

```
        Bitmap B = new Bitmap(chosenGoldenLineBottom.Width, chosenGoldenLineBottom.Height + chosenImageSupp.Height + chosenGoldenLineTop.Height);
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(B))
        {
            g.DrawImage(chosenGoldenLineTop, 0, 0, 1540, 49);
            g.DrawImage(chosenImageTop, 0, chosenGoldenLineTop.Height, 308, 560);
            g.DrawImage(chosenImageJungle, chosenImageTop.Width, chosenGoldenLineTop.Height, 308, 560);
            g.DrawImage(chosenImageMid, chosenImageTop.Width + chosenImageJungle.Width, chosenGoldenLineTop.Height, 308, 560);
            g.DrawImage(chosenImageAdc, chosenImageTop.Width + chosenImageJungle.Width + chosenImageMid.Width, chosenGoldenLineTop.Height, 308, 560);
            g.DrawImage(chosenImageSupp, chosenImageTop.Width + chosenImageJungle.Width + chosenImageMid.Width + chosenImageAdc.Width, chosenGoldenLineTop.Height, 308, 560);
            g.DrawImage(chosenGoldenLineBottom, 0, chosenGoldenLineTop.Height + chosenImageTop.Height, 1540, 53);
        }
```

// Section C

```
            B.Save(System.IO.Path.Combine(
            Environment.GetFolderPath(
            Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop),
            "Team Awesome v3" + ".png")); 
           // Saves on the desktop
        }
```

I've devided the big batch of code into 3 section for your ease, A, B and C.
Simply said:
Section A gets 7 images.
Section B combines the 7 images into 1 bigger image.
Section C saves the image to the desktop.

I'm very pleased with that already. But, I'm sure Users would like to be able to Select a specific location to save this 1 bigger image at, at least I would.

Now, the solution I'm trying to find is either a Control that can Save the 1 bigger image to a user chosen location, that could replace Section C.

OR

A Control that selects a specific location and is able to give back a Path to which I can save the 1 bigger image, replacing only a single argument of Section C.

I've tried an array of many different things, that turned out ineffective or failed at first attempt. Such as the FileDialog system (which is unavailable in asp.net), and the FileUpload Control, which only uploads a file to the programm and not the other way around.

Note how one could try to get a Path from the FileUpload control and try to create an illusion to the User that he's saving the file. But, one does not simply insert the FileName editing (before saving, like in any normal case) into the FileUpload control, neither can you actually select a Directory, you'd have to Select a File and cut off the FileName in the Path, resulting in a Confusing experience for the User.

I've spend around 17 hours trying to find a solution, but I've failed.
Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

User save are browser dependent , asp.net works in sandbox for security reasons cant change that. Maybe a plugin/add-on on browser can help you achieve functionality, but its still highly unlikely with solution you are trying.

with a browser add-in you can achieve it by let it listen to the web url and then give  prompt to user to save file which will actually cut-paste the file saved in user system(say temp folder).
But again a browser addin will be needed to installed on user browser which is both optional for users and written differently for each browser.
regards

Comment: That seems quite difficult.

Allright, then I have 3 options considering the feedback:
1."Finding a specific add-on that is universal and enables my wished for functionality"

2."Making 2 buttons, 1 of which Saves the image to the desktop like now, and the other which (along with a textbox) allows the user to fill in a specific Path to which the image will be saved"

3."Wait for alternative solutions"


For now I'll wait for alternative solutions, since I only asked this  1 hour ago. Thereafter I'll either use those answers or go with Option 2.

Thx for your effort Alok ;)